# Flutter Dio Form Data post giving 400 error response DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [400]

Tags: flutter, api, dart, form-data, dio

Does anyone know why this call is failing?  It's working in postman but failing with Dio.  I've tried wrapping it in the fromMap call and it was no different than how I have it below.  Do Form Data calls simply not work with Dio?

```
createAccessToken(
  {required String username, required String password}) async {

var requestBody = {
  "username": username,
  "password": password,
  "clienttype": clientType,
  "requestcontext": requestContext
};

//FormData formData = FormData.fromMap(requestBody);

try {
  Response response =
      await _dio.post<Map<String, dynamic>>(uri + 'authenticate.ashx',
          data: requestBody,
          options: Options(headers: {
            "User-Agent": "curl/7.42.1",
            "Accept": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          }));

  print('User created: ${response.data}');

  String token = response.data['access_token'];

  //accessToken = TokenData(response.data);
  prefs.saveToken(response.data['access_token']);
} catch (e) {
  print('Error creating token: $e');
}
```

}

This call is returning a DioError (DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [400]

In postman...

[PostMan Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYVS8.png)

[PostMan headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naKxT.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
userLogin(
    String password,
    String mobile,
  ) async {
    try {
      String url = "url";

      Dio dio = Dio();

      dio.options.headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      };
      var response = await dio.post(url, queryParameters: json.encode({
        "password": password??"",
        "mobile": mobile??"",
      }));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response.data;
      } 
     else{
       print(response.data);
       return "request failed";
       }
     }catch (e) {
      return e.toString();
    }
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I'm still getting a 400 error.